# Creating a cube using arrays and for loops

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, jpanel

I'm currently working on a program in class, but got stuck at a point where I have to use a for loop to draw the lines of the cube. Can anyone help me out a little here? I've looked online for help, but couldn't get help on this program using a FOR loop.

Original Question:
Write an application that draws a cube. Use class GeneralPath and method draw of class Graphics2D.

This is what I have down so far:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CubeJPanel extends JPanel
{

   public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
   {
      super.paintComponent( g );

      // base one: coordinates for front of the cube, point 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
      int base1X[] = { 100, 100, 200, 200, 100 };
      int base1Y[] = { 100, 200, 200, 100, 100 };

      // base two: coordinates for back of the cube, point 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
      int base2X[] = { 75, 75, 175, 175, 75 };
      int base2Y[] = { 75, 175, 175 ,75, 75 };

      Graphics2D g2d = ( Graphics2D ) g;
      g2d.setColor( Color.red );

      GeneralPath cube = new GeneralPath();

 // this is where i'm having trouble. I know i'm suppose to for loop and arrays to draw out the lines of the cube.



  g2d.draw( cube );
   } // end method paintComponent
} // end class CubeJPanel
```

Answer (score 0):

The base1X, base1Y are x coordinates along a drawing area, with (0,0) being the top left corner of the panel. To use a GeneralPath you need to something like this:

```
GeneralPath cube = new GeneralPath();
cube.moveTo(base1x[0], base1y[0]);

for(int i=1; i<base1x.length(); i++)
{
   cube.lineTo(base1x[i], base1y[i]); 
}
cube.closePath();
```

The above code segment will draw a single square, which are all of the points in base1. Basically think of GeneralPath as connect the dots. You first have to move the path to a starting location. moveTo will move the drawer to the point, without drawing a line. The lineTo will draw a line from your current point to the point in the moveTo. Lastly, be sure to close the path.

Figure out the correct order to draw the points and you should be able to figure out how to iterate over the points.